# Moving Files around and maintaining references?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to move files within VS Code that are required/imported (node project) and have it automatically update those references?

Would be so helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The May release (version 1.24) of VSCode has this ability ([update import paths](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_update-import-paths-when-a-file-is-moved-or-renamed)) for javascript and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

did a little more research on the plugin front with different search criteria and there are a few that do this sort of thing...

this is the one I ended up going with: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.move-imports